# logstash grok filter regular expression works in debug tool but failed in actual execution

Tags: regex, logstash, grok

I'm trying to extract a filed out of log line, i use http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ to debug my regular expression with:

```
(?<action>(?<=action=).*(?=\&))
```

with input text like this:

```
 /event?id=123&action={"power":"on"}&package=1
```

i was able to get result like this:

```
{
  "action": [
   "{"power":"on"}"
 ]
}
```

but when i copy this config to my logstash config file:

```
input { stdin{} }

filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "(?<action>(?<=action=).*(?=\&))"}
  }
}

output { stdout {
  codec => 'json'
}}
```

the output says matching failed:

```
{"message":" /event?id=123&action={\"power\":\"on\"}&package=1","@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-01-05T10:30:04.714Z","host":"xxx","tags":["_grokparsefailure"]}
```

i'm using logstash-2.1.1 in cygwin.
any idea why this happen?

Comment: Try using `\baction=(?<action>[^&]*)` or even `[?&]action=(?<action>[^&]*)`. The negated character class `[^&]` will make it less greedy, and should be more efficient and potentially solve other issues.

Comment: thank you, this works works for me, as you said by making it less greedy, will help avoid lots of problems

Comment: Please consider also upvoting my answer if it proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might experience an issue caused by a greedy dot matching subpattern `.*`. Since you are only interested in a string of text after `action=` till next `&` or end of string you'd better use a negated character class `[^&]`.

So, use

```
[?&]action=(?<action>[^&]*)
```

The `[?&]` matches either a `?` or `&` and works as a boundary here.

Comment: Please consider also upvoting my answer if it proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't answer your regexp question, but...

Parse the query string to a separate field and use the kv{} filter on it.

Comment: Thank you for offer this approach, i tried to match the query string by %{URIPATH} but turns out it can't capture the string starts with "{"

Comment: The curly brace is allowed in URIPATH; it's the double-quote that's not part of that pattern.  Use a different pattern.